# How to match for the part of a line after a pattern using Emacs regular expression

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

How to match for the word dog and cat in the following lines.

```
The dog

The cat
```

The word at the beginning of the line("The") remains same.
The words "dog" and "cat" changes and this is the word to be matched.

The regular expression should match for the word after the word "The" but not "The".

Comment: Can you clarify your question: Will it always match only "dog" or "cat"? Will the preceding word always be "The"? In other words, can you generalize your question?

Comment: You should clarify whether you're talking about regexp searching interactively, e.g. with `M-x replace-regexp` or programmatically. If the latter, Michael Markert's answer will help you.

Comment: Regular expression is used in program, not interactively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do you want:

```
The \(\w+\)
```

The word after `The` is then the `\1` Group.

In elisp that's

```
(replace-regexp "\\(\\w+\\)" "\\1")
```

Comment: Just to add a little info, in the program it should be used as "\\(\\w+\\)" and "\\1".

Comment: That's not right: In a string it has to be "The \\\(\\w+\\\)" and "\\1". Just "\\(" would be evaluated to "(".

Comment: On second thought: You were probably bitten by escaping, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs regexps do not feature zero-width assertions, so you *cannot* avoid matching that preceding text, if it is critical to the pattern.

You can, of course, use grouping to isolate the parts of the matched string that you are interested in (as per Michael Markert's answer).